# Error while processing the cube: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, cube, olap-cube

I am getting following error while processing SSAS cube using powershell script. Error is "There is not enough space on the disk." However there is 2 TB memory allocated on the server and the estimated cube size is not more than 8 GB. Can some one please advise me on why i am getting this error and how to resolve it.

The following system error occurred from a call to GetOverlappedResult for Physical file: '\?\K:\OLAP\Data\xxx.0.db\xyz.0.cub\Factx.0.det\Factx.0.prt\131.fact.data', **Logical file: '' : There is not enough space on the disk. .**
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the 'Factx' partition of the 'Factx' measure group for the 'Factx' cube from the xxx database.
Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure the disk space available is on the correct drive (K:)? Is this drive a local disk? Is it accessible for the user under which the Analysis Services service runs?

Comment: @Frank, K: drive is not a local disk but i am sure the user has access to the drive. We run the process every day , its success until yesterday when i added more data it resulted in failure, when i remove the newly added data and rerun the prcoessing, it succeed.

Comment: Is there a quota on the K: drive for the user under which the Analysis Services service runs? Does the processing write any files at all, or is this the first write attempt? Are you possibly hitting the 2TB limit (http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2010/02/18/understanding-the-2-tb-limit-in-windows-storage.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Check the settings for TempDir under the advanced settings on your SSAS instance. By default this is set to c:\ and if your cube is heavy on aggregations they can be written out to TempDir as the cube processes and can fill up pretty quickly. Change the TempDir to a folder within your k:\ drive or similar.